# Very slow application execution when debugging (android 9, miui 11)

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, debugging, miui

Issue has showed up after updating my Xiaomi Mi Mix 2 from miui 10 to miui 11 (and from android 8 to 9, api level 26 -> 28). When I'm attaching debugger using Android Studio to my application, it starts to execute extremely slow (one activity loads itself for up to 15 secods (sic!), when normally it's ~1-2s). When I run my app on emulator (in debug mode of course), everything works normally and smoothly. Before update it worked fine on my phone during debugging.
The question is: is it normal behavior on hardware with android 9 or something is wrong with my phone? I did not find any threads with similar issue.

Comment: I have same problem. Could you solve the problem?

Comment: Same problem on my Mi6 with MIUI Global 11.0.3

Comment: same issue on debug mode miui 11.0.4

Answer (score 0):

Method debugging can be the reason for it. You might have forgotten to remove it. I have this slow debugging sometimes. For me the main reason for slow debugging was having method breakpoint. I make whole debugging slow.  Go to view breakpoint in your debugger. And remove the method breakpoint that you might have forgot to remove.

Comment: this actually did help me. i removed allmy breakpoints andit started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to **turn off** MIUI Optimization to make app debugging faster. My MIUI version is Global 11.0.3.

> Go to Settings > Additional Settings > Developer options > Turn on MIUI optimization to off.

Just turn MIUI optimization on after debugging, they still recommend it to be ON.

Comment: Nothing has changed after disabling this "optimization" :( .